# emacs psvn, how to view the svn-commit log message?

Tags: svn, emacs, logging

A user is allowed to attach text log on svn commit.
Is there a way to see that text message in emacs specifically in psvn mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M-x svn-status-show-svn-log` will display the log.

The default psvn binding  is the finger-twisting: `C-x M-s f l`.

Answer (score 1):

`C-x v l` (vc-print-log) will show the version control log of the current buffer's file.  I'm not familiar with psvn, it may have other ways to access the same information.